# Is this code converting the KUTTypeFileURL as a String, then converting it to a NSPasteboard.PasteboardType?

Tags: swift, type-conversion

Going through a tutorial and trying to make sense of the Swift syntax for the first parameter of this method call. A guard statement nested in a for/in loop. The line is pulling out the string containing the URL for the pasteboard item being dragged.

Is this code converting the KUTTypeFileURL as a String, then converting it to a NSPasteboard.PasteboardType? What else could be going on here.

```
guard let stringyURL = item.string(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeFileURL as String)) else { continue }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [kUTTypeFileURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kuttypefileurl) is a CFSting.
- `kUTTypeFileURL as String` bridges it to a `String`
- `NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeFileURL as String))` is a `NSPasteboard.PasteboardType`
- `item.string(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeFileURL as String))` is asking the `NSPasteboard` for the string representation (as a `String?`) of all items that match the provided type, i.e. all `URL`s.
- Then the guard statement is unwrapping the resulting `String?`, binding it to `stringyURL`.

In other words, this is a really silly and round-abound way to simply say `item.string(forType: .URL`)`